# By default the forms are out of order

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I reload the webpage the form go on top of each other. My code CSS is:

```
<style>
.paragrafo {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 70%;
   float: right;
   right:-300px;
   position:relative;
   top:-200px;
   }
  .paragrafo1 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 70%;
   float: right;
   right:-300px;
   position:relative;
   top:-200px;
   } 
<style>
```

And my html code is:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" >
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value=1  onclick="Form('form_1')" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Privato</label>
  </div>
 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" onclick="Form('form_2')" value=2>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Azienda</label>
</div>

<form id="form_1" class="row g-3" value=1 selected="selected" method="GET" onsubmit="check_login_users()" action="Paginautenteloggato.html">    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="md-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail12" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail12" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">inserisci qui la tua email</div>
  </div>
</form>

<form id="form_2" type="hidden"class="row g-3"style="display:none;" value=2 onsubmit="check_open_new_window_negoziante()">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="md-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail13" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail12" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">inserisci qui la tua email</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

By default the form there aren't at their place instead when I select the radio button, the forms take their place. Why? How can I do?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now there is no way to see what is happening. And it sounds like a styling issue. Include the relative CSS as well.